# The probability that a robot on Mars will work longer than 800 days is 0.2.

Tags: probability

The probability that a robot on Mars will work longer than 800 days is 0.2. Five robots have been deployed on the planet. what is the probability that after 800 days of service at least one of them will still work?

---

Is this as simple as $1-0.8^5$?

Comment: Your method is correct IF we assume the robots fail (or don't fail) independently of each other.  That seems like an unnatural assumption (perhaps the robots fail because of an event that effects more than one of them, say).  Of course, for a probability problem you can go ahead and assume it, but then the assumption should be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is that simple. The probability that any given robot will fail before 5 years have passed is $0.8$, so the probability that they have all failed by then is $0.8^5$. Meaning the probability of at least one functioning robot after five years is $1-0.8^5$.